# Shuffling questions in exam

Tags: exam, random

If I want to shuffle the question to prepare four different questions papers having same questions but with the different question numbers, what should I do?

[image]

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{exam}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,dsfont}
    \setlength\parindent{0pt}
        %usage \choice{ }{ }{ }{ }
        %(A)(B)(C)(D)
        \newcommand{\fourch}[4]{
        \par
                \begin{tabular}{*{4}{@{}p{0.23\textwidth}}}
                (a)~#1 & (b)~#2 & (c)~#3 & (d)~#4
                \end{tabular}
        }

        %(A)(B)
        %(C)(D)
        \newcommand{\twoch}[4]{

                \begin{tabular}{*{2}{@{}p{0.46\textwidth}}}
                (a)~#1 & (b)~#2
                \end{tabular}
        \par
                \begin{tabular}{*{2}{@{}p{0.46\textwidth}}}
                (c)~#3 & (d)~#4
                \end{tabular}
        }

        %(A)
        %(B)
        %(C)
        %(D)
        \newcommand{\onech}[4]{
        \par
              (a)~#1 \par (b)~#2 \par (c)~#3 \par (d)~#4
        }

        \newlength\widthcha
        \newlength\widthchb
        \newlength\widthchc
        \newlength\widthchd
        \newlength\widthch
        \newlength\tabmaxwidth

        \setlength\tabmaxwidth{0.96\textwidth}
        \newlength\fourthtabwidth
        \setlength\fourthtabwidth{0.25\textwidth}
        \newlength\halftabwidth
        \setlength\halftabwidth{0.5\textwidth}

      \newcommand{\choice}[4]{%
      \settowidth\widthcha{AM.#1}\setlength{\widthch}{\widthcha}%
      \settowidth\widthchb{BM.#2}%
      \ifdim\widthch<\widthchb\relax\setlength{\widthch}{\widthchb}\fi%
      \settowidth\widthchb{CM.#3}%
      \ifdim\widthch<\widthchb\relax\setlength{\widthch}{\widthchb}\fi%
      \settowidth\widthchb{DM.#4}%
      \ifdim\widthch<\widthchb\relax\setlength{\widthch}{\widthchb}\fi%
      \ifdim\widthch<\fourthtabwidth
        \fourch{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
      \else\ifdim\widthch<\halftabwidth
        \ifdim\widthch>\fourthtabwidth
          \twoch{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
        \else
          \onech{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
        \fi
      \fi\fi
    }
    \begin{document}
     \begin{questions}
    \question If $a = 3 + i$ and $z = 2 - 3i$ then the points on the Argand diagram
    representing az, 3az and - az are
    \choice{Vertices of a right angled triangle}{ Vertices of an equilateral 
    triangle}{Vertices of an isosceles triangle}{Collinear}
    \question If z represents a complex number then $\arg (z) + \arg\left(\bar z\right)$ is 
    \choice{$\dfrac{\pi}{4}$}{$\dfrac{\pi}{2}$}{0}{$\dfrac{\pi}{6}$}
    \question If the amplitude of a complex number is $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ then the number is
    \choice{ purely imaginary}{purely real}{0}{neither real nor imaginary}
    \question The value of $i + i^{22} + i^{23} + i^{24} + i^{25}$ is
    \choice{i}{-i}{1}{-1}
    \question The volume generated by 
    rotating the triangle with vertices at
    (0, 0), (3, 0) and (3, 3) about x-axis is
    \choice{$18\pi$}{$2\pi$}{$36\pi$}{$9\pi$}\end{questions}
    \end{document}

    \end{document}
```

That is I need to mark the question paper given above as Code A. And I need to print another question paper which marked as Code B and in this question paper the first question Code A should be in question number 5 (say) and similarly others also should have different positions...

Comment: May be you should try something else like exsheets.

Comment: `az, 3az and - az` should be `$az$, $3az$ and $- az$`. There are other places with the same formatting problem.

Comment: You can also have a look at the esami package which does what you want.

Comment: This python script seems to shuffle the questions: https://github.com/gcalmettes/examRandomizer/
But this is an external script and there seems to be so bugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You go for exam design. Here I am sharing a work. You can open this in sharelatex.
Visit: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/52e3f06d3cf27e7a050000ee

Comment: ya.. its a good work.. But i could find the error as " Undefined control sequence" at the end.. what should i do?@Dr Amit

Comment: That error is due to keyword \mathbb. So, we can use \usepackage{amsfonts}